# GraphQL - resolve JSON as array of graphql types to support batch querying

Tags: postgresql, graphql, graphql-tools, postgraphile

I've got a collection of graphql services that are combined together in a gateway using `graphql-tools` schema stitching.

Here's some sample code for reference:

```
async function makeGatewaySchema() {
  // define the remote executors, introspect the subschemas, etc.
  return stitchSchemas({
    subschemas: [
      {
        schema: postSubschema,
        executor: postExecutor,
        batch: true,
      },
      {
        schema: userSubschema,
        executor: userExecutor,
        batch: true,
      },
    ],
    typeDefs: `
    ...
    extend type User {
      posts: [Post]
      batchPostsJSON: JSON
      batchPosts: [Post]
    }
    ...
  `,
    resolvers: {
      User: {
        posts: {
          selectionSet: "{ id }",
          resolve(user, args, context, info) {
            return delegateToSchema({
              schema: schemaPost,
              operation: "query",
              fieldName: "postsByUserId",
              args: { id: user.id },
              context,
              info,
            });
          },
        },
        batchPostsJSON: {
          selectionSet: "{ id }",
          resolve(user, args, context, info) {
            return batchDelegateToSchema({
              schema: schemaFavorite,
              operation: "query",
              fieldName: "postsByUserIds",
              key: user.id,
              argsFromKeys: (ids) => ({ ids }),
              valuesFromResults: (results, keys) => {
                return keys.map((id) => {
                  return results.filter((f) => f.user_id === id);
                });
              },
              context,
              info,
            });
          },
        },
        batchPosts: {
          selectionSet: "{ id }",
          resolve(user, args, context, info) {
            return batchDelegateToSchema({
              schema: schemaPost,
              operation: "query",
              fieldName: "postsByUserIds",
              key: user.id,
              argsFromKeys: (ids) => ({ ids }),
              valuesFromResults: (results, keys) => {
                // doesn't matter, we don't get here
              },
              context,
              info,
            });
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });
}
```

In the example code above, I have three ways to get posts associated with a user:

#### 1: `User.posts`

This works fine but isn't batched

#### 2: `User.batchPostsJSON`

This is batched very nicely and works perfectly with one problem: the `JSON` return type doesn't allow me to query `Post` fields - I just get all of them no matter what.  Worse, if `Post` was related to some third type, I wouldn't be able to follow that relationship.

#### 3: `User.batchPosts`

This allows me to query fields of `Post`, but throws an exception - I've defined the return type as array of `Post`, but `JSON` is what comes back and I get an error in the gateway.

Is there a way to handle the JSON returned by the subschema and pretend that I'm really getting `[Post]` back instead?  By the time my `valueFromResults` is finished, that IS what it will look like.  The problem is that the return type mismatch between my typedef and the actual resolver throws an error before I have the chance to reformat the return value.

Comment: What do you mean by "*but JSON is what comes back*"? What "*error in the gateway*" do you get specifically?

Comment: What are `postSubschema`, `schemaPost` and `schemaFavorite`?